# Incompatible pointer type warning using NSOpenPanel

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsopenpanel

I had some code I used to open text files and it was working good, but now some parts of it are deprecated so I changed them to make it work without any error.
I finished with a new code that it is working fine but it gives me a warning that I can not understand how to fix it...
here is my code:

```
-(IBAction)openMyFile:(id)sender
{
    int i;

    NSOpenPanel* openDlg = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSURL *myUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:documentsDirectory]; //before here I had setDirectory but now is deprecated
    [openDlg setDirectoryURL:myUrl];

    [openDlg setCanChooseFiles:YES];

    [openDlg setCanChooseDirectories:YES];


    if ( [openDlg runModal] == NSOKButton )
    {

        NSArray* files = [openDlg URLs]; // here I had [openDlg filenames] but now is deprecated

        for( i = 0; i < [files count]; i++ )
        {
            NSString* fileName = [files objectAtIndex:i];

            NSString *content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:fileName encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil]; //HERE IS WHERE I GET THE WARNING
        }
     }
}
```

The warning I'm getting says:

> incompatible pointer types sending 'nsstring *__strong' to parameter of type 'nsurl *'

and it comes out when I try to pass the content of the file in the NSString *content but anyway content is filled with the content of the file... everything seams to work good...
Any help would be very much appreciated... Peace - Massy

Comment: You're passing an NSString where an NSURL is expected..

Comment: You're right... I just had to change NSString with NSUrl and it is ok... Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[openDlg URLs]` returns an array of *URLs*, not *strings*:

```
NSArray *files = [openDlg URLs];
for(i = 0; i < [files count]; i++)
{
    NSURL *fileURL = [files objectAtIndex:i];
    NSString *content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:fileURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help... d4Rk pointed me to the right direction... but as you wrote the solution as an answer I will get yours as the "green one".
Thanks again... Peace - Massy